# TCL writing socket

Tags: tcl, webservice-client

Does TCL provides a functionality to listen to external servers?

I want to create a socket with TCL-based client-side, which gonna listen to not TCL-based server-side. In the common case I'm gonna send XML (SOAP) message and I'm gonna wait for some response, which gonna be some kind of mask.

If TCL does support such functionality, please help me with some hyper-links to already existing API's or some other posts!

Any help is useful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/):  http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/OpenTcp.htm

Comment: Tcl can be both a TCP server and a TCP client, and in the same process too. It can even (on Unix) have client sockets passed in correctly as stdin/stdout and still understand them. You might want to try to explain more exactly what you want to know though.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: It will be like a web service. I'm going to build a client-side socket using TCL which will retrieve some information from external system (for sure there isn't any TCL functionality) through SOAP messages exchange.

Comment: I suggest that you try [TclSoap](http://tclsoap.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Have you looked into http://core.tcl.tk/tclws which provides server and client-side webservices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl does support sockets. You can either write your own WS client implementation using the `socket` [command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/socket.htm), you can use the Tcl [http package](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1475), or the [TclSoap](http://tclsoap.sourceforge.net/) library as @Johannes13 suggested.